# How do I assert the title text of a UINavigationController in Subliminal?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, subliminal

I'm new to writing Integration Tests with [Subliminal](https://github.com/inkling/Subliminal). And I want to test if a certain View Controller is shown after the user taps a button. What would the best way to test this?

- Can I get the top most view controller with Subliminal and find it's title?
- Can I get the top most view controller and compare its class?
- Can I the title label of the Navigation Controller?

At the moment I only managed to get the title label of the Navigation Controller by its accessibility label, like this:

`SLElement *titleLabel = [SLElement elementWithAccessibilityLabel:@"Welcome"];
SLAssertTrue([[UIAElement(titleLabel) label] isEqualToString:@"Welcome"], @"It should show the Welcome screen");`

But then I would just be testing if `@"Welcome" == @"Welcome"`. And a *welcome* label might appear in the view hierarchy of other view controllers as well.

What would be your approach to test and assert if the View Controller shown after a user's action is indeed the view controller that I am expecting?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

To identify an object in your accessibility hierarchy that can't be described (or can't be *uniquely* described) by a combination of its accessibility label, value, and traits, your best bet is to use `[SLElement elementMatching:withDescription:]`.  The method is used like this:

```
SLElement *titleLabel = [SLElement elementMatching:^BOOL(NSObject *obj) {
    // Code to test objects (obj parameter) in the accessibility hierarchy,
    // and return YES or NO depending on whether or not obj is the particular
    // object you're looking for.
} withDescription:@"A description of the view for Subliminal to use in logs/error reports"];
```

What goes in the matching block depends on the structure of your app and what exactly you're trying to identify, but remember that you can put essentially arbitrary code there to evaluate the input accessibility element `obj`.  You could inspect `obj.accessibilityLabel` and if that label is equal to to `@"Welcome"` then (verify that `obj` is a `UIView`) and walk up the view hierarchy looking for a particular view or class (maybe `UINavigationBar`) that proves that `obj` lives inside your navigation controller.  Or you could just test the class of `obj` and look for something that appears only in the particular navigation controller that you're trying to verify has appeared.

Another tool that you can use to approach problems like this is a Subliminal [app-hook](https://github.com/inkling/subliminal/wiki/Writing-Tests#manipulate-the-application-directly).  You can register objects in your application (either classes *or* specific instances) to respond to messages from Subliminal tests.  So if, for example, your application delegate knows whether or not this view controller was/is shown, you might register the application delegate to respond to an message indicating whether or not the view controller was shown, and in your test code you can use `SLAskAppYesNo` to find out whether or not the view controller was/is shown.